# System.out.println("何人ですか？");にエラーが出ました。

Tags: java

下記のコードで `System.out.println("何人ですか？");` にエラーが出ました。

＊エラーは下記
この行に複数マーカーがあります

```
    - 構文エラーがあります。")" を挿入して MethodDeclaration を完了してください
    - 構文エラーがあります。"SimpleName" を挿入して QualifiedName を完了してくだ
     さい
    - 構文エラーがあります。"Identifier (" を挿入して MethodHeaderName を完了し
     てください
    - トークン "." に構文エラーがあります。このトークンの後には @ を指定する必要があり
     ます
```

エラーの内容がすべて当てはまらないように思います。
文法的にエラーはないと考えておりますが、エラーが出ます。

例えば以下、

- 構文エラーがあります。")" を挿入して MethodDeclaration を完了してください

")" が不足している箇所がないはずですが、どう対応したらいいか教えていただきたいです。

---

**ソースコード:**

```java
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class main {
    
    System.out.println("何人でプレイしますか？");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    String name = br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: [compilation error: identifier expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520497)

Comment: クラス名が`main`であったとしてもその中に`mainメソッド`が無いからでは？ [Javaの実行に欠かせないmainメソッド、その仕組みからしっかり解説](https://www.bold.ne.jp/engineer-club/java-main) それからそれが通ると次の対処が必要になるでしょう。[Javaのエラーに対処するプログラムを書く](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/0401/08/news125.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メソッドして実装する必要があります。

```java
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("何人でプレイしますか？");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        String name = br.readLine();
    }
}
```